# what is the correct way to use Python typing when creating numpy/pandas objects?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mypy, typing

I've been using numpy/pandas for years but have only recently started type checking all my code with mypy.

The following example shows code that works as intended but doesn't pass mypy. What is the correct way to add type annotation to this example ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_repeats(date: pd.Timestamp)->np.ndarray:
    return np.repeat(date,3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    today=pd.Timestamp.utcnow()
    repeats=get_repeats(today)
    print(repeats)
```

Edit: the mypy error is

```
minimal_example.py:5: error: Argument 1 to "repeat" has incompatible type "Timestamp"; expected "Union[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]], _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]]], bool, int, float, complex, str, bytes, _NestedSequence[Union[bool, int, float, complex, str, bytes]]]"
```

Comment: "doesn't pass mypy" – what does it say, and where?

Comment: added this to the op

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the docs, technically speaking `np.repeat` requires an *arraylike* first parameter](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat), and a timestamp isn't one.

However, a timestamp in a list is. In other words,

```
def get_repeats(date: pd.Timestamp) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.repeat([date], 3)
```

makes mypy happy:

```
$ mypy zup.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
$ cat zup.py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def get_repeats(date: pd.Timestamp) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.repeat([date], 3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    today = pd.Timestamp.utcnow()
    repeats = get_repeats(today)
    print(repeats)
```

Comment: This solution unfortunately doesn't make mypy happy. I still get the error.

Comment: It did make my PyCharm _and_ Mypy happy. Newest Mypy at the time of writing, `pandas-stubs` installed.